# Bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1)^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm studying a set of lecture notes which posits the existence of a bijection between $(0,1)$ and the set of infinite sequences of elements in $(0,1)$. The bijection is
$$
s = 0.t_1 t_2 t_3 \mapsto (s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots),
$$
where $s_1 = 0.t_1 t_3 t_5 t_7 \ldots$, $s_2 = 0.t_2 t_6 t_{10} \ldots$, and so forth. I believe the general formula is
$$
s_i = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} i (2k-1)10^{-k}, 
$$
but I'm not 100% sure on this.

I'm trying to prove that this map is in fact a bijection. Here is a sketch of what I have so far. For injectivity and well-definedness, I'm fairly sure that I need to require (though the notes do not) that infinite strings of $9$'s are forbidden, so the decimal expansions $s = 0.t_1 t_2 t_3 \ldots$ termintes in $0$'s instead of $9$'s if the decimal expansion of the corresponding element of $(0,1)$ is non-unique. I believe injectivity follows immediately from that assumption, since if the image of $s$ and $s'$ are the same, then $t_i$ and $t_i'$ are equal for every $i$ and I can reconstruct $s$ and $s'$. Surjectivity is less clear, but I think I can write out a sequence of elements in $(0,1)^{\mathbb{N}}$ and then directly decide which elements of the domain are necessary to construct that decimal expansion.

Is this on the right track?

Comment: This doesn't look surjective. Consider the fact that the first digit (after zero) of, e.g., $s_3$ will always be the same as the second digit (after zero) of $s_1$. Clearly not all possible sequences with values in $(0,1)$ will have this property.

Comment: @AnCar I'm not sure I'm able to follow this. I tried writing out an example. Let's take $s = (0.123456789 \ldots)$ (and just repeats) and $s' = (0.234567891)$ (and repeats). Then $s_1 = 0.1357 \ldots$ and $s_2 = 0.3579 \ldots$. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you find $s$ such that $s_1=0.01$ and $s_3=0.2$?

Comment: The "and so forth" comes too early for clarity here.  The next elements in the sequence should be $s_3 = 0.t_4 t_{12} t_{20} \ldots$, $s_4 = 0.t_8 t_{24} t_{40} \ldots$.

Comment: The codomain is also too small to get a well-defined function: for example, if you apply it to $s = 0.01010101\ldots$ then you would get $s_1 = 0.000000 = 0 \notin (0, 1)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Ah ok, that makes more sense. I assumed the formula $s_i=\sum_{k=1}^\infty i(2k-1)10^{-k}$ was correct.